# Exception from VB.NET Comparison Statement

Tags: vb.net

Here is the exception:

"Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Here is the line of code that that throws the exception (confirmed from stepping through in the debugger):

```
If LoanData.Item("ApplicationId") <> "" AndAlso LoanData.Item("ApplicationId") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try LoanData.Item("ApplicationId").toString()?

Comment: It *is* a crummy exception message.  Comparing floating point values by comparing their string representation has its own major failure scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

`LoanData.Item("ApplicationId")` is returning a double probably.

You're trying to compare it with a String.

If this is the problem you could just do this:

`LoanData.Item("ApplicationId").ToString()  <> ""`

Comment: ApplicationId is being returned from an 'int' field on the database, the primary key of a table actually. I'm not sure how 'Double' is even in this error at all.

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in `LoanData.Item("ApplicationId")` must be of type `Double`.

The VB.NET compiler is letting you use the `<>` operator only because you must have `Option Strict Off`. It is assuming the value of `LoanData.Item("ApplicationId")` must be a `String` and is attempting to cast accordingly.

Since the value is *not* a `String`, you're getting an `InvalidCastException`.

Instead of using the `<>` operator, you can use `Equals` instead, which will result in a call to the `Equals` method of whatever type the value of `LoanData.Item("ApplicationId")` happens to have (or the `Object.Equals` method, if that type has not overridden it):

```
If Not LoanData.Item("ApplicationId").Equals("") AndAlso LoanData.Item("ApplicationId") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

This should exhibit the closest possible behavior to what you currently have without resulting in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting, btw, that VB6 would allow one to compare a double to a string directly, but this broke the transitive property of comparisons since "9" would be greater than "8Q", and "8Q" would be greater than the double 10.2 (since the double would be converted to a string in that case), but the double 10.2 would be greater than "9" (since the string would be converted to a double in that case).  Eeks.